# application path in codeigniter in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

My system's path is `C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter` and my application folder is inside the system folder. I am facing the following error..

> Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/core/CodeIgniter.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\index.php on line 202
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\index.php on line 202

Answer (score 0):

Your system path should be:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\system
```

And your app path should be:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application
```

Did you change these?

Your index.php file cannot find the path you specified which means the path is probably incorrect unless you are having permission issues.

Comment: application path is `codeigniter\application` not `codeigniter\app`